# Can we highlight all the Detected Planes in the ARCore app?

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

At present, there is ***circles texture*** comes up whenever a Plane is detected in the scene but I want to highlight all the area of the plane instead of the small circle in the center.

Is it possible to highlight the Detected Plane in the ARCore app?

I am using Java for `ARCore`/`Sceneform` for Android apps in Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

**The answer is: YES**.

You can easily customize a detected planes' visualization in ARCore. By default, the scene has a `PlaneRenderer` public class that highlights detected planes when they have been detected, i.e. it renders a texture in `.png` file for them. A texture `.png` file is located in **src/main/res/drawable** (it's a `R.drawable.custom_texture`).

Here is a code:

```
Texture.Sampler sampler =
    Texture.Sampler.builder()
        .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR)
        .setMagFilter(Texture.Sampler.MagFilter.LINEAR)
        .setWrapMode(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
        .build();

Texture.builder()
    .setSource(this, R.drawable.custom_texture)
    .setSampler(sampler)
    .build()
    .thenAccept(texture -> {
        arSceneView.getPlaneRenderer()
        .getMaterial().thenAccept(material ->
            material.setTexture(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture));
    });
```

All you need to do is to modify the default material and texture used to render detected planes.

[image]

Comment: I could able to change the texture now but with this i still have the same circle spot light and not the actual image i used for texture. see the image and its screen shot after implementation from [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7iw7x91u0iwvsxz/AAADgB5hk7teqcRJb-kjrP3Qa?dl=0)

Comment: Sorry, but at the moment it's not possible to get rid of edge feather. There's no accessible method to do it.